# Are there any good video tutorials for protex?

Tags: miktex, texmaker, tutorials

I just downloaded and installed MikTex and TexMaker today, and was wondering if you have any advice. I'm starting to read through various wikipedia tutorials, and other guides, but videos would be an immense help!

Comment: The important part really isn't handling the program/editor (Texmaker), but understanding LaTeX code. For beginners, I highly recommend reading [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), which gives you a thorough overview.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to LaTeX, here's a 12-video playlist on YouTube that might be of use to you:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDD406480D35CE390

Comment: there's also http://spoken-tutorial.org/Study_Plans_LaTeX presented at tug 2011 (proceedings arrived here yesterday...)